# how to pull (fetch) total feeds from Instagram using instagram-node

Tags: node.js, instagram

I have a problem using the instragram-node NPM package. At the moment I am getting only 18-20 feeds using it, but I would like to fetch my all posted images.

This is my code I am running this after getting the access token:

```
    var instaApi = require('instagram-node').instagram();
instaApi.use({
    access_token: ig_token_access
});
instaApi.user_self_feed(function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {
    console.log(medias);
});
```

Is there a way fetch all data ?
Please give me some help to pull my total posts on instagram.